# Qt creator - `multiple definition of qMain` error

Tags: c++, qt

I started to work  for my homework using QT creator to make the GUI, but I gt this error and I can't manage to find the reason for it, nor can I understand what it means. I suppose it sees my main function twice but I do not know why... please assist me in fixing this error:

error:

```
Makefile.Debug:155: warning: overriding commands for target `debug/main.o'
    Makefile.Debug:142: warning: ignoring old commands for target `debug/main.o'
    debug/main.o: In function `Z5qMainiPPc':
    D:\c++\Labs\GUI_r/../../../info/qt/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/mingw/include/QtGui/qwidget.h:494: multiple definition of `qMain(int, char**)'
    debug/main.o:D:\c++\Labs\GUI_r/main.cpp:7: first defined here
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "controller.h"
#include "StudentRepository.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    StudentRepository *stre = new StudentRepository();
    Controller *c = new Controller(stre);
    MainWindow w(c);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

edit: long code removed - not the reason for the error. Check the answere it is useful.

Comment: Right click your project > Clean Project then Run qmake and the re-build your project

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to find out the origin of the problem if you don't share a complete minimal source code to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: @karlphillip : This sounds like he should post entire project and we'll all do the work for him...

Comment: @Evgeni k did that long ago...

Comment: @Agent_L: you are not supose to work for me it is jsut maybe someone knows that kind of error... its all about saying 'it is there...' and i`ll fix it on my own.

Comment: show your .pro file and qconfig.pri

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for that linking error is because of awkawrd behaivior behalf QT creator. I had in the projectName.pro  -

```
QT       +=    core gui

TARGET = GUI_r
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    main.cpp \                   /////// Double call of main.cpp
    StudentRepository.cpp \
    controller.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    controller.h \
    StudentRepository.h \
Student.h \
ui_mainwindow.h \        /////Double call of ui_mainwindow.h 
ui_mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Thank you, i hope this post will be usefull to other new users of QTcreator.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe your project contains another source file with a main. Somewhere files duplicated. Check "SOURCES =" and main.cpp in your .pro file.

Comment: @user1388172 It doesn't mean anything what you have opened. All that matters is what's written in the files.

Comment: I know what classes i built there aren't so many... no class is called like that.

Comment: @user1388172 He means look in your `.pro` file and check there aren't duplicate `main.cpp` entries.

Comment: cbamber85 i jsut got that idea  yup that was it, Thanks! make i  liek a post so i can vote you and so people know in the future about this posibility

Answer (score 2):

You can only have **one** `QApplication` per program!

Review your classes (Controller, StudentRepository, MainWindow) and make sure that they are not declaring `QApplication` as well.

Comment: No class named by is is with that name, checked also to make sure.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to find out the origin of the problem if you don't share a complete minimal source code to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: i add more if that necessary.

Comment: It is necessary :) To able to reproduce your problem, we need to have the exact same code you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 1):

It does see two definitions of `qMain` , not your main.

You have probably taken a sample program and modified it by adding your code. Recreate those steps and see when it stopped working.
When writing a code, do a compilation as often as possible, to find such errors right after you've introduced them.

Comment: i have actually written it by myself but after i made the graphical interface it crushed.